# SSLHandshakeException in Android

Tags: android, sslhandshakeexception

My app is trying to access my server and download a PDF. I'm getting SSLHandshakeException, my server is having `https` certification with `Go Daddy`. Certificate is valid till 2015.

Even in my devices trusted certificates, I can see `Go Daddy` as trusted certificate. Please suggest me some solution:

This is my exception:

```
08-04 02:35:01.740: W/System.err(19591): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
08-04 02:35:01.740: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:413)
08-04 02:35:01.740: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:257)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:210)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:477)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at com.virinchi.activity.LoginActivity$UnSignedDownloadManager.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:626)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at com.virinchi.activity.LoginActivity$UnSignedDownloadManager.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:163)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:593)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    ... 17 more
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
08-04 02:35:01.750: W/System.err(19591):    ... 22 more
```

This is my code for certification checking:

```
public class SSLFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public SSLFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
}

public SSLFactory(SSLContext context) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
   super(null);
   sslContext = context;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

public static HttpClient sslClient(HttpClient client) {
    try {
        X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() { 
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLFactory(ctx);
        ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = client.getConnectionManager();
        SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
        sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));
        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, client.getParams());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the error? I'm not into SSL so I have no clue what a trust anchor is. "Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found"

Comment: Create your own FakeSocket using `SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory and X509TrustManager` and implement them while making the request.

Comment: @jitainsharma Please find my update where I'm implementing my certificate check. Please let me know for any changes!!

Comment: Use `SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to install the intermediate certificate on your webserver. It should be availabe from the distributor of the certificate.